# Apply custom WHERE condition based on a parameter

Tags: sql, where-clause, sql-server-2016

I have a stored procedure that contains a query with multiple conditions in the WHERE clause.

I can call this stored procedure with 2 different parameters. If I call it with 'X' parameter, I would like to apply a specific condition, however if I call it with 'Y' parameter, I would want to not apply that condition.

However, the remaining conditions in the where clause should apply to both 'X' and 'Y' parameters.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tbl_1 t
WHERE 1 = 1
    -- I want these two conditions to apply to both 'X' and 'Y' parameters
    AND EXISTS (SELECT ..... WHERE value = @Param)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ..... WHERE value = @Param)

    --and lastly the third condition should only be applied if I have 'X' parameter when calling this procedure
    AND (@Param = 'X'
         AND t.ApptDt > '02/02/2023'
         AND t.CallDt > '02/1/2023')
```

This logic doesn't seem to work. If I call this with 'Y' parameter I get no values, unless I comment out this last bit.

How can I implement this type of logic?

Thanks.

Comment: `AND (@Param != 'X' OR (t.AppDt > '02/02/2023' AND t.CallDt > '02/1/2023'))` probably

Comment: I would EDIT your post and show more complete the procedure.  You have your "X" Param and other strange exist/not exist.  Maybe posting the core of the stored procedure would help offer better and more clear answers vs ambiguity that might have a cleaner solution.

Comment: @DRapp I thought the explanation above my code was sufficient in explaining what the process does, and how I would like for it to behave. I think, taking time to explain what the EXISTS/NOT EXISTS do not really benefit the question. I wanted to have a simple example. My apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then try changing your LAST condition
FROM

```
AND (@Param = 'X'
     AND t.ApptDt > '02/02/2023'
     AND t.CallDt > '02/1/2023')
```

to

```
AND (   @Param = 'Y'
     OR (@Param = 'X'
        AND t.ApptDt > '02/02/2023'
        AND t.CallDt > '02/1/2023')
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tbl_1 t
WHERE 1 = 1
    -- I want these two conditions to apply to both 'X' and 'Y' parameters
    AND EXISTS (SELECT ..... WHERE value = @Param)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ..... WHERE value = @Param)

    -- The third condition should only be applied if I have 'X' parameter when calling this procedure
    AND ((@Param = 'X' AND t.ApptDt > '02/02/2023' AND t.CallDt > '02/1/2023')
         OR @Param <> 'X')
```

Comment: I don't like the use of additional variable. But other than that I guess it does

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can use a case clause, just safe the else case is true when the param is diferent to X
Sorry for my english
ej

```
select *
from tbl_1 t   
where case when @Param = 'X'
            then t.ApptDt
        else '19000101'
    end > '20230202';
```

Comment: This answer is should be accepted.
Appreciable!!!!!